# Windows hosts file alternative without needing admin rights?

Tags: windows, dns, proxy, non-admin

I was inspired by DNS66, an app available to Android, which used a fake DNS server that dropped outgoing DNS requests to certain hosts. This way, it didn't need to modify the /etc/hosts file, thus not needing root. Is there a Windows alternative that does the same thing? I would like to redirect system-wide traffic from two hosts to two different ones. For example:

```
 94.23.155.247 example.com
 94.23.155.243 test.com
```

I would also like to run this behind a proxy. Is this possible?

Comment: Your best bet is probably just to set up a small DNS server with BIND. However, BIND does require administrative privileges and since you mentioned a proxy, you might need some otherwise special configuration which may or may not be possible (depending on the setup). You might wish to clarify why you have these requirements or otherwise further detail your network configuration.

Comment: If you have control over the hostnames to resolve you could take a look at https://nip.io/ . `example.com.94.23.155.247.nip.io` resolves to 94.23.155.247